# How to specify jQueryUI Tab Target Panel?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

Whats the cleanest way to specify a shared target panel for jQueryUI tabs when all the content is loaded via AJAX and the target lies outside of the parent "tabs" div?

For example:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="link1.html" title="Go to Link 1"><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="link2.html" title="Go to Link 2"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="link3.html" title="Go to Link 3"><span>Link 3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="link4.html" title="Go to Link 4"><span>Link 4</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="panel">Content should be loaded here.</div>
```

EDIT: I would prefer to have a unique title attribute per link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is not possible with the current release of jQueryUI (1.7.2) without event modification.

I have submitted a [patch](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4607) for consideration for a more graceful solution.

Comment: That patch wasn't accepted btw. Any followup to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use `aria-controls` attribute on `li` tag to select the `id` of panel

```
<div id="tabs">
   <ul>
     <li aria-controls="panel"><a href="link1.html"><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
     <li aria-controls="panel"><a href="link2.html"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
     <li aria-controls="panel"><a href="link3.html"><span>Link 3</span></a></li>
     <li aria-controls="panel"><a href="link4.html"><span>Link 4</span></a></li>
   </ul>
  <div id="panel" >Content should be loaded here.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your target div a title, e.g.:

```
<div id="panel" title="contentPane">Content should be loaded here.</div>
```

and give your tab links the same title:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="link1.html" title="contentPane"><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="link2.html" title="contentPane"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="link3.html" title="contentPane"><span>Link 3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="link4.html" title="contentPane"><span>Link 4</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there another method you are aware of without using the title attribute?

Comment: @Matt - No, not that I'm aware of, and as I recall I spent a considerable amount of time figuring out the above. If you do find something, please share the knowledge :)

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect the requirement of unique title attributes.

Comment: you actually need to give your target div an `id` of `contentPane`, but otherwise this works... thx!

Comment: doesn't work with jquery ui 1.9.0 - I need a solution so badly now