# jQuery UI tabs using aria-controls instead of title to have a single panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I need to update a legacy project which uses jquery UI 1.8 to the latest 1.13

I'm facing an issue in jQuery 1.9 the tabs widget had massive breaking changes, the current implementation (1.8) has all the tabs in a single panel and using the title attribute to tell each of these remote tabs the panel to use

According to the migration [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-url-method-and-use-of-title-attribute-use-aria-controls-attribute) title was replaced with `area-controls`
It doesn't seem to be a simple replacement as I'm not able to get the new tabs widget to use a single panel with remote `href`, `area-controls` doesn't seem to have any effect

An example of how this might be achieved would be great, otherwise, I'll have to rewrite all the legacy code to deal with different panels for each tab (I tried :| it will take forever)

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/et3rnal/sbrzd1fk/69/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to update the URL manually during the activation event, but I think I found how the new way meant to work. Simply the new element `aria-controls` needs to be added to the `li` not to the link `a` (at least this is where the legacy code I have has the title added to)

```
<div id="tabs">
   <ul>
     <li aria-controls="panel"><a href="link1.html"><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
     <li aria-controls="panel"><a href="https://jsfiddle.net/about"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
     <li aria-controls="panel"><a href="https://jsfiddle.net"><span>Link 3</span></a></li>
     <li aria-controls="panel"><a href="link4.html"><span>Link 4</span></a></li>
   </ul>
  <div id="panel" >Content should be loaded here.</div>
</div>
```

I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18063699/3086744)

example https://jsfiddle.net/et3rnal/v79hpygr/1/